# Generic type param in interface

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I have an interface,

```
    interface A<in T> {
        fun onSuccess(response: T)

        fun onFailure() 
    }
```

And accessing it in a call in methods,

A utility method where i want to do something common for all methods,

```
private fun process(l:A<Any>){}
```

and few other methods

```
private fun method1(l:A<B_CLASS>){
   process(l)
}

private fun method2(l:A<C_CLASS>){
   process(l)
}
```

But `B_CLASS` is not compatible type of `Any`.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `A<Any>` with `A<*>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [star projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) in place of `Any`:

```
private fun process(l: A<*>) { }
```